# Get the first item of filtered list

Tags: scheme

There is `some` in `clojure`, which can be expressed in `chicken scheme` as following:

```
(define (some pred coll)
  (lazy-head (lazy-filter pred (list->lazy-seq coll))))
```

Is there something built-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`find`](http://api.call-cc.org/doc/srfi-1/find) from [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html)—it works just like your implementation:

```
(find even? '(3 1 4 1 5 9)) ; => 4
```

Note, however, that is is *slightly* different from Clojure's `some`: Clojure returns the value of `pred` applied to the element, whereas `find` returns the element itself.

See also [`any`](http://api.call-cc.org/doc/srfi-1/any), also from SRFI 1, which is preferable if you don't need the value, just a check for existence.